# Will line breaks/whitespace in HTML affect how the page is displayed?

Tags: html

Will inserting line breaks in HTML like this affect the output?

```
<header>

    <div id="someid">

        something here

    </div>

</header>
```

I've been trying to study web development, and different tutorials use different formats. Will the extra lines between tags affect the output? I personally would prefer it that way since as a newbie, it looks more readable to me.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the answers guys! Was gonna upvote every answer, but sadly, I am new here. 

Thank you again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No - whitespace is collapsed in the output.

Primarily that means two things:

1 - Leading/trailing whitespace in an HTML element is not displayed, so these two divs will display the same:

`<div>Some stuff</div>`

```
<div>     Some stuff

</div>
```

2 - Multiple whitespace characters in a row will be collapsed into one space.  That means these two divs will display the same:

`<div>Some stuff</div>`

```
<div>Some              stuff</div>
```

Here's [a nice article](http://www-sul.stanford.edu/tools/tutorials/html2.0/whitespace.html) for further reading.

Comment: It's not really stripped, it's just that it isn't significant and doesn't make a difference to the rendering.

Comment: Good point - answer clarified with more details, changed "stripped" to "collapsed".

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the link and the explanation! Currently reading it right now, have a nice day!

Comment: Happy to help, welcome to SO! If this answer was helpful, you can click the check mark to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not.  I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
<header>

    <div id="someid">
        <br>
        something here
        <br>
    </div>

</header>
```

The `<br>` tag produces a newline in text.

Answer (score 0):

Whitespaces are ignore from the output, at one or two exceptions (fortunately, you can see this at an advanced level only)

You can put 1 blank line or 1000, the result will be the same

Answer (score 0):

Linebreaks won't affect the rendering, but multiple whitespaces are collapsed into a single space, which might make a difference.

For example, when you're indenting tags for readability the output will have a space between the tags. When your intention is for those elements to sit directly next to each other you'll find they don't.

[See this link](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) for examples and techniques to combat the unwanted space.

Answer (score 0):

No,.. but sometimes yes.

At an old job they had to remove newlines and indents from divs because of some bad bootstrap grid CSS (an early unofficial copy that mutated over time) that they used across all their sites.

This was a really weird issue that baffles me and we basically had to always make sure our closing tags for 'cols' were on the same line as the next opening tag with no whitespace at all.

Eventually, I stopped this by convincing them to use an official bootstrap grid.